# Configuration Promotion Between Environments

Tags: configuration, configuration-files, environment, configuration-management

**What is a good way to coordinate configuration changes through environments?**

In an effort to decouple our code from the environment we've moved all environmental config to external files. So maybe the application will look for `${application.config.dir}/app.properties` and `app.properties` could contain:

```
user.auth.endpoint=http://some.url/user
user.auth.apikey=abcd12314
```

The problem is, `user.auth.endpoint` needs to point to a test resource when on test, a staging resource when on the staging environment, and a production resource when on prod.

We could maintain different copies of the config file but this would violate DRY and become very unwieldy (there are 20+ production environments).

**What's a good way to manage this?** What tools should I be searching for?

Answer (score 1):

Externalizing config is a good idea, you could externalize them all the way to environment variables.

> Env vars are easy to change between deploys without changing any code;
>   unlike config files, there is little chance of them being checked into
>   the code repo accidentally; and unlike custom config files, or other
>   config mechanisms such as Java System Properties, they are a language-
>   and OS-agnostic standard.

From http://12factor.net/config

Comment: Excellent link! I'm not opposed to using env vars but I'm still in the same boat; locally I've got `export SOME_CONFIG=/location/of/resource` which is different in each environment. How do I get that promoted to production without having to rely on a process of telling someone and risk them mistyping the environmental variable?

Comment: I guess you are looking for something like the product I work for:  http://www.thoughtworks-studios.com/docs/go/current/help/dev_use_current_revision_in_build.html#job but I'm not aware of a standalone solution other than maybe memcached.

Answer (score 1):

I know of three approaches to this.

The first approach is to write, say, a Python "wrapper" script for your application. The script will find out some environmental details, such as hostname, user name and values of environment variables, and then construct the appropriate configuration file (or a set of command-line options) that is passed to the real application.

The second approach is to embed an interpreter for a scripting language (Python, Lua and Tcl come to mind) into your application. This makes it possible for you to write a configuration file in the syntax of that embedded scripting language. In this way, the configuration file can make use of the scripting language's features, such as the ability to query environment variables or execute a shell command (such as `hostname`) and use if-then-else statements to set variables appropriately.

The third approach (if you are using C++ or Java) is to use the open-source [Config4*](http://www.config4star.org) library (disclaimer, I am the main developer of that). I recommend you read Chapter 2 of the "Config4* Getting Started" manual to see examples of how its flexible syntax can enable a single configuration file adapt to multiple environments.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at http://www.configapp.com. You work with 1 configuration file, and switch/tab between the environments. Internally it's just 1 configuration file, and it handles the environment variables and generates the config file for the specific environment. In Config terminology, you have 1 Prod environment with 20+ instances. You will have a Prod environment configuration and you can tweak the 20+ instances accordingly using a web interface.

You moved environment specific properties to a separate file, but with Config, you don't have to do that. With Config, you can have 1 configuration file, with environment variables support, and common configuration applied to all environments.

Note that I'm part of the Config team.